# View time taken of last command in fish shell

Tags: time, fish

I'm aware that I can use `time` as

```
time <some command>
```

But this requires me to remember to type `time` before `<some command>`

I'm wondering if it's possible create some sort of hook, so that `time` is run for every command, but only displayed if I enter `last-time` or something at the cli.

An example usage might be:

```
$ sleep 2
$ last-time

________________________________________________________
Executed in    2.00 secs      fish           external
   usr time    2.28 millis  912.00 micros    1.37 millis
   sys time    0.30 millis  296.00 micros    0.00 millis
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$CMD_DURATION` variable contains the duration of the last-run interactive command, in milliseconds.

```
$ sleep 2
$ echo $CMD_DURATION
2014
```

[Docs are here](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#envvar-CMD_DURATION).

Answer (score 1):

You can use certain fish shell themes which provide such info right in the UI itself.

E.g. `oh-my-fish` has `bobthefish` shell.

```
sudo apt-get update
curl -L https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/raw/master/bin/install > install
fish install
omf install agnoster bobthefish
```

[1]  : https://gist.github.com/frfahim/ec020bc98fc5e52a74f1c12a82710546

[2]  : https://github.com/oh-my-fish/theme-bobthefish